How does nuxt3 handle $fetch 403 error and jump to login page
I refer to the official nuxt sample to handle http errors: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/recipes/custom-usefetch#custom-fetch
But my code didn't work as expected, when the http status code was 403, in the ssr scenario, the error page would be displayed directly instead of jumping to the login page
fill-background.vue
<template>
   ......
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
......

interface OptionObject {
    id: string;
    label: string;
}
const promptOptions = ref<OptionObject[]>([])
const res = await aiFillBackgroudApi.promptOptions()
if (res.success && res.data) {
    promptOptions.value = res.data
}

......
</script>

plugins/api.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const api = $fetch.create({
        onRequest(context) {
            // ......
        },
        async onResponseError({ response }) {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => {
                    navigateTo("/user/login");
                });
                return;
            }
        },
    });

    return {
        provide: {
            api,
        },
    };
});

plugins/error-handler.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.hook("app:error", async (err) => {
        console.error("app:error: ", err);
    });
});

Access Error Page

Server Console Log

I want to be able to navigate to the login page instead of displaying a 403 error when I encounter an http 403 status code. What to do?
